# Site Not Appearing Correctly in IE

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I am working on dermatologytech.org/ and have gotten the markup as W3 valid as I could. When I view the site in internet explorer it does not appear right, the buttons appear all the way up. See the picture below. Additionally, the navigation is shifted in FireFox. See second image. Any assistance would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post your HTML,css or jsfiddle is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey now you can do this easily just define

**min-height** of your **slider** div in your **css** file.

as like this

```
.slider{
min-height:266px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the CSS and PHP index (or maybe part) to help you troubleshoot? There might be a problem with your positioning as Internet Explorer does not support all CSS tags. I tried using IE 8 on your site and the output is okay. So maybe check your CSS file and look for CSS tags that are incompatible with IE 7 and look for a workaround. Check this out : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and this : http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

These sites may help you find what makes your layout change on IE.

Comment: It's IE 7 that it doesn't show up correct in. Should I post my entire CSS and PHP file?

Comment: Alex, you may listen to @Sam. We cannot help you much if we do not know what's inside your CSS and PHP files.

Comment: BTW, Why did you tagged wordpress, is this a wordpress deployment?